# Prevent publishing composer package?

Tags: composer-php

`npm` has a [`private`](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/files/package.json.html#private) option to prevent [accidental] publishing, does `composer` have a similar option?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, since you can't publish something accidentally. You have to browse to packagist.org, log in, create a new package, including a link to the github repository and save the package.

Comment: I will bet five English pounds that someone has done this accidentally - http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0706382/quotes?item=qt0401325